# Append element to beginning of list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

How do I append an element to the beginning of a list in Prolog? I need the end result to be called like so:

```
pushFront(8, [3, 1], NewList). % NewList is now [8, 3, 1].
```

I have tried to implement it as follows:

```
pushFront(Item, [], [Item|_]). %Problematic
pushFront(Item, [OldDequeH|OldDequeT], NewDeque) :-
    leftPush(OldDequeH, OldDequeT, [Item|NewDeque]).
```

But it does not work, and I'm out of ideas tbh. Can anyone describe what is wrong with my implementation and what changes it needs to work properly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To add an element at the beginning of a list, just use list notation:

```
pushFront(Item, List, [Item|List]).
```

The list representation uses internally the cons functor (`.`), so a list `[b,c,d]` is just syntactic sugar for `'.'(b,'.'(c, '.'(d, [])))`.

This representation allows you to add an item at the front just by wrapping another cons functor, i.e. if you want to a add an item a at the front of a list `L` you would wrap a `'.'(a, L)`, which we usually write simply as `[a|L]`.

Comment: Holy! It's that simple...I'm such an idiot sometimes, thanks btw :)

Comment: Question: Why do you refer to cons as a functor not a function?

Comment: @MathuSumMut: In Prolog there are no functions (unless you consider the ones used in the right hand side of `is`), you have user procedures and system predicates. But here you are using just a structure (a list) for which Prolog has two representations (list representation, as in `[item,item|TailItems]` and _cons_ representation (the dot functor `.`). You can build a list (structure) by using either the list representation or the _cons_ representation, which uses the dot functor.